# From localhost to UK2 - My login scripts no longer work

Tags: php, sql, database

I have spent the last few months creating a website locally on my PC.
I have now purchased a domain and uploaded my files, and database.

For some reason I cannot think of, users can no longer login to the website - and I have also check my login credentials with UK2.net and they said they are all correct.

What might be going wrong?

**Login Form:**

```
<form action="login.php" method="post" >
    Email<br />
    <input name="email" type="text" /><br /><br />
    Password<br />
    <input name="password" type="password" /><br />
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Log In" />
</form>
```

**Login PHP:**

```
require_once('/scripts/includePDO.php');

$error = '';
$form = $_POST['submit'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if( isset($form) ) {
if( isset($email) && isset($password) && $email !== '' && $password !== '' ) {

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE email = :email and password = :password";

$q   = $conn->prepare($sql); // the default way of PDO to manage errors is quite the same as `or die()` so no need for that
        $q->bindValue(':email',$email,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $q->bindValue(':password',$password,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $q->execute();

            $r = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            if(($r)!=0)

{ //success

$answer = $r['id'];

$_SESSION['logged-in'] = true;
$_SESSION['who'] = $answer;

//If the login details are entered and they match those in the database, forward to new page.
header('Location: /home/');

exit;

// If information is wrong or missing, provide error message.
} else { echo "Sorry, something hasn't worked. Are you entering all the information correctly?"; }
} 

}
```

Comment: Can you share the hosted apps url.

Comment: Are sessions/cookies working otherwise? And what's happening, blank screen, PHP/MySQL error, *"Sorry, something hasn't worked"* nothing happens, etc. My clients tell me things "aren't working" all the time and it's like pulling teeth to get the details...

Comment: change `if(($r)!=0)`  to `if($r)`  and see what happens!

Comment: nothing still happens with that change #undone

Comment: OK, it will let me echo out content until it hits includePDO.php, then it wont echo anymore. This is the file that connects to the DB that UK2.net said contained all correct usernames, passwords etc

Comment: Is it possible that require_once is not allowed? I will not echo the first line placed into that file either

Comment: Then I guess the problem is that file because that file doesn't exist on server

Comment: One question: **script**  directory is in your document root?

Comment: Have you checked that the Userid and Password you use in your includePDO.php have been changed to match the userid and password on the LIVE server? And come to that that the domain is correct as well. I would expect all these things to change between development and live environments when you move a site to a live environment.

Comment: Yes, all those details are correct. The page is loading further now... as far as the 'header /home/' section. It's just not forwarding to that page though

Answer (score 0):

The answer was -

There was a slash before scripts/includePDO.php that did not need to be there, which made it impossible to find the file.

Comment: You can enable error reporting, then PHP will tell you "I can't open the file because it does not exist or I'm not allowed" ...

Comment: using `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `ini_set();` - http://blog.flowl.info/2013/enable-display-php-errors/

Comment: Oh my gosh. I don't know what happened because all i did was add your coding there, and it coincidentally started working!!